# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=='

Tags: php, wordpress

I am getting:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '==' (T_IS_EQUAL), expecting ')'

```
<?php 
if ( empty ( bp_loggedin_user_id() == false ) ) {
    $user_id = bp_loggedin_user_id();
    echo bp_core_fetch_avatar( array( 'item_id' => $user_id) );
} else {
    echo get_avatar($id_or_email, $size='64', $default, $alt='User name' ); 
}
?>
```

Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: Did you read the error at all? If you look on the line number, it tells you exactly what you're missing, and where. `Unexpected '=='`...hmmm, that means it expected something BEFORE that. `expecting ')'`...hmmm, I guess I need an extra `)` before the `==`.

Comment: I am not a php programmer. and thought if I removed the '==' it will broke the method. Don't know why I am getting thumb down for it.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you probably are because: https://www.google.com/search?q=Parse+error%3A+syntax+error%2C+unexpected+%27%3D%3D%27+(T_IS_EQUAL)%2C+expecting+%27)%27&oq=Parse+error%3A+syntax+error%2C+unexpected+%27%3D%3D%27+(T_IS_EQUAL)%2C+expecting+%27)%27&aqs=chrome..69i57.280j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever we use any function which returns some value with `empty()` like OP it will throw an error `Cant use return value to write con....`. So always first store the value in a variable and then check it.

It should be

```
$loggedIn = bp_loggedin_user_id();
if ( empty ( $loggedIn) == false ) {
```

Comment: I got at the same line this error after your fix:
Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context

Comment: updated my answer. this error comes when we check any function which return something with `empty()`.try to use it as mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Small typo error:

change this:

```
if ( empty ( bp_loggedin_user_id() == false ) )
```

TO this:

```
if ( empty ( bp_loggedin_user_id() ) == false  )
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo.

```
if ( empty(bp_loggedin_user_id()) == false ) {
    ....
}
```

Also, check this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

> Prior to PHP 5.5, empty() only supports variables; anything else will result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not work: empty(trim($name)).

So if you are using PHP <5.5, you have to use variables:

```
$result = bp_loggedin_user_id();
if ( empty($result) == false ) {
    ...
}
```

Also, `empty()` returns boolean, so you can do this:

```
$result = bp_loggedin_user_id();
if ( !empty($result) ) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
if ( empty ( bp_loggedin_user_id() == false ) ) {
```

with either

```
if ( empty ( bp_loggedin_user_id()) == false ) {
```

or (the better version as it improves readability)

```
if ( !empty ( bp_loggedin_user_id() ) {
```